# Upload image with some other parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I upload image with some other parameters I write this code but can't success in this code I got some error how to resolve this issue

also change parameters type(NSDictionary & String type) and Alamofire update pod.

I face this line Error

```
 multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
   withName: key)
```

error is

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'data'

Code  is Hear

```
let  parameter : NSDictionary = ["auth_key": UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstants.kAuthKey)!,
                                     "userid" : UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstants.kuserId)!,
                                     "eventname" : self.txtEventName.text!,
                                     "eventdescription" : self.textviewDescription.text!,
                                     "event_categories" : self.arrSelectEventID,
                                     "eventshop" : self.selectedOrganizerID,
                                     "eventreef" : self.selectedReefID,
                                     "event_start_date_time" : self.Startdate,
                                     "event_start_time" : self.startTime,
                                     "event_end_date_time" : self.Enddate,
                                     "event_end_time" : self.EnfTime,
                                     "meeting_location" : self.MeetingPoint,
                                     "meeting_location_address" : meetingAddress,
                                     "meeting_location_latitude" : meetinglat,
                                     "meeting_location_longitude" : meetingLong,
                                     "event_ticket_price" : self.txtEventTicketPrice.text! ,
                                     "event_ticket_qty" : self.txtEventTicketQuantity.text!,
                                     "eventvideourl" : self.txtVideoURL.text!,
                                     "recurrence_type" : "none" ,
                                     "end" : self.End,
                                     "end_type" : self.EndType,
                                     "end-count" : self.EndCount,
                                     "create_ticket_on_event" : ""]


    let image = self.imgCover.image
    let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)




    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        // import image to request
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "eventimage", fileName: "profile.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        for (key, value) in parameter {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)

        }
    }, to: strURL,

       encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in

            }
            upload.responseJSON
            { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization


            if let JSON = response.result.value
            {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                var dic = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: dic!["message"] as? String  , preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                }))

            }
    }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    })`
```

Comment: Change value.data to "\(value)".data with a backslash before the open parenthesis.

Comment: @ElTomato  i change this code " multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key as! String)" image uploading success but parameters was not passed in server side.

Comment: Do you read "with a backslash before the open parenthesis"

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you have more problems.

Comment: @ElTomato .    Yes i write backslash before "value".data........

Comment: The problem is that the values in your `NSDictionary` are of type `Any`. So it has no way of knowing that it was a `String`, so it wasn’t able to resolve the `data` method. If you change `parameter` to be `[String: String]` rather than `NSDictionary`, then it will be able to resolve this.

Comment: did you find solution @miteshmewada

Comment: Yes i solve my issue @NavinBagul  i just update this line 


`multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as! String)`

.  and its work properly

Answer (score -1):

I am using this code, Hope so it helps

```
    func jsonCall(withMultipleImagesImage productImages: [UIImage]?, withfieldName strfieldName: String?, classURL urlClass: String?, witCompilation completion: @escaping (_ Dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

        self.AddProgressHud()
        //NSError *error;
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        // the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
        let BoundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"
        // string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
        let FileParamConstant = strfieldName
        // the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
        let url = URL(string: "\(urlBase)\(urlClass ?? "")")
        print("url is \(String(describing: url))")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
//        if userDefaults.value(forKey: userdefaultAuthHeader) != nil {
//            //request.setValue(userDefaults.value(forKey: userdefaultAuthHeader) as? String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
//        }
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        // set Content-Type in HTTP header
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=\(BoundaryConstant)"
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        // request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        // post body
        let body = NSMutableData()
        var count = 0
        for image: UIImage in productImages!{

            count += 1
            let imageData = UIImage.jpegData(image)
            //UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            if imageData != nil {
                if let anEncoding = "--\(BoundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
                if let anEncoding = ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(String(describing: FileParamConstant!))\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n ").data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
                if let anEncoding = ("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n").data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)

                }
//                if let aData = imageData {
//                    body.append(aData)
//                }
                if let anEncoding = "\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
            }
        }
        if let anEncoding = "--\(BoundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
            body.append(anEncoding)
        }
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        request.httpBody = body as Data
        // set the content-length
        //let postLength = "\(UInt((body as Data).count))"
        //request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")


        // set URL
        request.url = url!
        print("re url \(request.url!)")
        var postDataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

        postDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in

            if error == nil {
                var dicjson: [AnyHashable: Any]? = nil
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
              //      self.hud.hide(animated: true)
                }
                print("\(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")")
                if let aData = data {
                    dicjson = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: aData, options: []) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
                }
                completion(dicjson, error)
            } else {
                print("erro \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
              //      self.hud.hide(animated: true)
                }
                completion(nil, error)
                //GlobalClass.showAlertwithTitle("Server Error", message: error?.description)
            }
        }

        postDataTask?.resume()

    }
```

If you are using alammofire then refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393767/9977451)

Comment: NavinBagul i use alammofire and i try same code of you share link but i facing in when i pass other parameters than "multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)" this line show me error "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'data' " and i update this line multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as! String) 

and it's  not showing me error but parameters vas not passed in server

Comment: @miteshmewada replace "value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!" with "value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!" and try again

Comment: I try this code but when i pass Array(some multiple data parsing) then it was crashed .

Comment: @miteshmewada your parameters should be  let parameters =  ["key" : value , "key" : value] as [String : AnyObject], its looks like typecasting issue